# Bug report on user reputation leagues

Tags: support

This bug:
[image]

You see, in the user reputation leagues page, the user named Karu ranked 9th of this month has a +7021 change, however they only have a total reputation of 3896, how is this possible? I am sorry my math isn't very good, but unless this user has a reputation of -3125 yesterday, this simply can't be true, can reputation even be negative?

Can anyone explain this?

This also applies to user goncalopp, you see they have a +438 reputation change yesterday, but they only gained 350 this month, so they should have -88 net monthly reputation change the day before yesterday and gain 438 reputation yesterday, though it is possible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "change" is relevant to the "rank" column, not the reputation.

As in they have moved up over 7,000 positions in rank. For a newish user who provides good contributions this is not that extraordinary. Many thousands of contributors will be new users who see maybe one or two upvotes and so no real rank change. By comparison 3000 rep is a lot.

Comment: That makes sense, though the word change does not clearly express the meaning it is supposed to mean...